# How to split a spark dataframe with equal records

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using df.randomSplit() but it is not splitting into equal rows. Is there any other way I can achieve it?

Comment: randomSplit should return datasets with approximately equal size if you pass the same weights. What is the problem? Do you want Datasets with exactly the same number of rows?

Comment: i am passing the weights as 1 for each split.
df_splits = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])) . is it possible to optimize this and get equal number of records.

Comment: it uses a sampling strategy which is random based, so the result will always be aproximate. To get exactly equally-sized dataframes, you would have to include some ordering and using multiple where statements, which would be considerably slower (and not random).

Comment: ok. So giving the weights as 1.0 for each split is fine ? df.randomSplit(([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))

Comment: It's fine, but the sizes will be only approximately equal. This should be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed balanced (equal sized) partitions in order to perform a specific cross validation experiment.

For that you usually:

1. Randomize the dataset
2. Apply modulus operation to assign each element to a fold (partition)

After this step you will have to extract each partition using `filter`, afaik there is still no transformation to separate a single RDD into many.

Here is some code in scala, it only uses standard spark operations so it should be easy to adapt to python:

```
val npartitions = 3

val foldedRDD = 
   // Map each instance with random number
   .zipWithIndex
   .map ( t => (t._1, t._2, new scala.util.Random(t._2*seed).nextInt()) )
   // Random ordering
   .sortBy( t => (t._1(m_classIndex), t._3) )
   // Assign each instance to fold
   .zipWithIndex
   .map( t => (t._1, t._2 % npartitions) )

val balancedRDDList =  
    for (f <- 0 until npartitions) 
    yield foldedRDD.filter( _._2 == f )
```